# GPS and google map using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, gps, ionic-framework

I used this link [enter link description here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places)for shown Google map but always he asks me of activated for the GPS .

My objective is: posted(Shown)the map without activated the GPS

after he shows my position

my controller :

```
facebookExample.controller('carteController', function($scope,$ionicPopup,$ionicLoading,$location,$cordovaGeolocation,$compile,$http) {

$scope.init = function() {
    var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

          $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            console.log("langitude et latitude obtenu par google maps");
            console.log(latLng);

            var mapOptions = {
              center: latLng,
              zoom: 15,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function(){

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: $scope.map,
                      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                      position: latLng
                  });  

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "Here I am!"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });

                  console.log(status);
```

please help me ,how to chnage my controller to reach my goal

Comment: please format your question better

Answer (score 1):

Your controller checks if the geolocation is available and then runs the map code. It is on this line:

```
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){
  //code here is only run if we got the current position
}
```

so you should get rid of that line if you do not want it. Problem then is: that you can not center the map on the user's position.
So also change that line:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
```

to

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397,150.644);
```

for example...

Comment: It is not my objective

Comment: it is...: posted(Shown)the map without activated the GPS. that is what the code will do, yet you have to show some place on the map...